# SVN over Samba / Dokan (sshfs)

Tags: svn, samba, connection

I have both SVN and Samba running on the same Debian server.

I have a shared folder, `dev`, in which I have a SVN checkout, `example`, of a project.

When I ssh to the server, I am able to do a `svn up example` from within the `dev` folder, no problem, however, when I connect to the Samba share and do a `svn log` (with TortoiseSVN in Windows) I get a 'connection refused' error and a note about removing `-q` from 'ssh' in '[tunnels]', however, I do not have a `-q` under '[tunnels]'.

This is my smb.conf file:

```
path = /var/chroot/www-data/
browseable = yes
read only = no
writable = yes
guest ok = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
force user = www-data
force group = www-data
mangled names = no
delete readonly = yes
```

I get the same errors when using Dokan instead of Samba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not so much Samba as it was SVN.

When I had done the checkout, I had used `svn+ssh://localhost/example.com`, so when I wanted to do a `svn log` or other commands from the Windows machine, Tortoise SVN tried to do a log on localhost/example.com, which of course was wrong. Switching to IP address instead of localhost solved the problem.